# How to Stop css for particular Page in Joomla?

Tags: css, joomla

I want to stop media/jui/css/bootstrap.min.css for my particular page in Joomla 3.1,
because I already insert some Css files in it,but same page following bootstrap.min.css.
so please help to stop bootstrap.min.css

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the link to the unwanted css file in the head of the HTML document to keep it from importing.

Cascading Style Sheets are called that partly because multiple sheets can be imported and the declaration with the highest priority will be used.  A complete definition of levels of precedence for css can be found in any css tutorial.

One way to get your own style sheet to take precedent over the standard template would be to import it after the template css imported by Joomla.  This way, according to order of precedence, your style sheet would be the most recently declared rule and should execute over the other one.  You would also be able to make the changes you care about without over-riding the rest of the template.

To get a more situation specific answer, it would be helpful if you would tell us what you have tried or include some code.

On the other hand, I find it hard to believe that you were unable to find any information on this topic in any standard css tutorial.  Try Google next time.

Comment: `You could remove the link to the unwanted css file in the head of the HTML document to keep it from importing.` This would remove it for the whole Joomla site.

Comment: I have to yield to your Joomla! expertise on this one, Lodder.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better solution using an extension for this, however you could try the following. Open the **index.php** for your template, find the line that is importing the CSS file and replace with the following:

```
$app   = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu   = $app->getMenu()->getActive()->id;
if ($menu !== 12){
    $doc->addStyleSheet(JUri::root() . "media/jui/css/bootstrap.min.css");
}
```

You need to change **12** to the ID of the menu item you wish to remove the CSS file from.

If `$doc` hasn't been defined, you can either add this inside the `if statement`:

```
$doc = JFactory::getocument();
```

or replace with the following:

```
JHtml::stylesheet(Juri::root() . "media/jui/css/bootstrap.min.css");
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The question is what is adding the bootstrap.min.css file? I guess you have to search for code like

```
JHtmlBootstrap::loadCss();
```

Because in Joomla 3 the template has to include bootstrap in their own CSS files. If this is not the case it can include the default bootstrap files with the code I mentioned before.

Bootstrap should never be loaded like

```
JFactory::getocument()->addStyleSheet(JUri::root() . "media/jui/css/bootstrap.min.css");
```

What you have to use is

```
JHtmlBootstrap::loadCss();
```

But this function should be called only from the template index.php file and not an extension, believe me I know what I'm talking about https://groups.google.com/d/msg/joomla-dev-general/c--P-HTzMzc/6fEujLeE4KgJ :-)

@Lodder you should use

```
$app   = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu   = $app->getMenu()->getActive()->id;
if ($menu !== 12)
{
    JHtmlBootstrap::loadCss();
}
```